# <span> to appear when hovering on <li>

Tags: html, css

Okay I have,

```
    <ul class="vertmenu">
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-logo">Logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-profile"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-bubbles2"><span>Connect</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-images">Designs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-insert-template">Templates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-star3">Effects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-code">Tutorials</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And my css looks like this:

```
.vertmenu {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #383433;
}

.vertmenu li a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -500em;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e9e5da;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.vertmenu li a:hover,
.vertmenu li:first-child a{
    background: #282322;
    color: #fff;
}

/* class for current item */
.vertmenu li.vertmenucurrent a {
    background: #282322;
    color: #e9e5da;
}

.vertmenu li a:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-indent: 0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.vertmenu li a.icon-logo:before {
    content: "V";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

---

This is a subtle vertical menu the lays on the left side of the page. Now the elements contain "icomoon" fonts and only this, so there is no explanation of what the button really is. Is it possible to have the text appear on the right side of the according parent when I hover over the li?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dpNw7/1/

Comment: Please provide a jsfidle, this will help people to help you. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You mention a `<span>` but I see none.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link. Where do I mention a span? EDIT: Oh in the title I mean <span> because I would like for either a <span> or <p> to appear.

Comment: I edited the code to better explain where I want the <span> element.

Comment: Where is the text that describes the menu item that you'd like to show on hover? You need it in the HTML from the start - use CSS to hide it initially and show it on hover.

Comment: @DACrosby the text is the <span> elements under the <ul>. i.e. "About" and "Connect".

Comment: Like this? I'm not sure what you mean to be honest. http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/dpNw7/2/

Comment: @DACrosby Sorry, this is my first question so it's a bit sloppy. That is what I want but imagine those buttons already containing icons. For example the first button "About" contains an icon of a profile. I can't show this because it will be tons of extra code. So what I'm getting at is to have the text show how you did, but on the right of the button.

Answer (score 1):

try to see this

```
    <ul class="vertmenu">
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-logo"><span>Logo</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-profile"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-bubbles2"><span>Connect</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-images">Designs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-insert-template">Templates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-star3">Effects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon-code">Tutorials</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.vertmenu {
    position: fixed;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #383433;
}

.vertmenu li a {
    display: block;
    color:#ccc;
    text-indent: -500em;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e9e5da;
    position: relative;
    /*text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.vertmenu li a:hover{
    text-indent: 0px;
}
.vertmenu li a:hover,
.vertmenu li:first-child a{
    background: #282322;
    color: #fff;
}
.icon-logo:hover span{visibility:hidden}
.vertmenu li a:hover span {
position: absolute;
color: #000;
top: 0;
left: 90px;
}
/* class for current item */
.vertmenu li.vertmenucurrent a {
    background: #282322;
    color: #e9e5da;
}

.vertmenu li a:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-indent: 0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.vertmenu li a.icon-logo:before {
    content: "V";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

/* (depends on total height of menu) */

@media screen and (max-height: 34.9375em) { 

    .cbp-vimenu {
        font-size: 70%;
    }

}
```

see this link http://jsfiddle.net/dpNw7/3/

Comment: @veechdzn if this answer is what you needed and actually solved your question, you might want to clic on the "accept answer" on the left of this answer, this is a gesture of grattitude for someone who spent his time on helping you C:

Answer (score 1):

So I tried to put some effort in this, is this what you are trying to fix?
I took the previous edits by DACrosby and edited some of my own coding.
Hopefully this will help you. You can just adjust the text of the link wherever you want to using `margin`.

HTML

```
<ul class="vertmenu">
    <center>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon-logo">Logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon-profile"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" /><div>About</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon-bubbles2"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" /><div>Connect</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon-images"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" /><div>Designs</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon-insert-template"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" /><div>Templates</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon-star3"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" /><div>Effects</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon-code"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" /><div>Tutorials</div></a></li>
    </center>   
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li img{
    margin: 13px 0 0 17px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.vertmenu li:hover img{
    display: block;
}
.vertmenu li:hover div{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 27px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.vertmenu {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #383433;
}

.vertmenu li a {
    display: block;
    color:#ccc;
    text-indent: -500em;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e9e5da;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.vertmenu li a:hover{
    text-indent: 0px;
}
.vertmenu li a:hover,
.vertmenu li:first-child a{
    background: #282322;
    color: #fff;
}

/* class for current item */
.vertmenu li.vertmenucurrent a {
    background: #282322;
    color: #e9e5da;
}

.vertmenu li a:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-indent: 0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.vertmenu li a.icon-logo:before {
    content: "V";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

/* (depends on total height of menu) */

@media screen and (max-height: 34.9375em) { 

    .cbp-vimenu {
        font-size: 70%;
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tweath/C25s5/